After restarting the game it does not spawn the targets
After i press restart button game restarts but it does not spawn the targets
when i first start the game it works but after restarting it does not spawn targets, cursor should also disappear and turn it crossheir. it tried many things but it does not work
public int totalHits = 0;
    public int ballHit = 0;

    public Image accuracyImage;

    public TextMeshProUGUI countDownText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI performanceText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ballHitText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI percentageText;

    public float countDown;
    public float accuracy = 0f;
    public float accuracyFA = 0f;

    public bool isGameOver = false;

    public FirstPersonController fpsScript;
    

    void Awake()
    {
        isGameOver = false;
        countDown = 120;
        StartCoroutine(Spawner());
        //InvokeRepeating("Spawner", 1, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        accuracy = ballHit * 100 / totalHits;
        if (countDown > 0)
            countDown -= Time.deltaTime;
        countDownText.text = (countDown).ToString("0");
        scoreText.text = accuracy + "%";

        if (countDown < 1)
        {
            isGameOver = true;
        }

        if (isGameOver)
        {
            GameOver();
        }

        accuracyFA = ballHit / totalHits;
        //Spawner();
    }

    IEnumerator Spawner()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            if (countDown > 0 && noOfBalls <= 3)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-270, 230), Random.Range(20, 180), 355);
                Instantiate(target, position, target.transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("Spawned");
                noOfBalls++;

            }
        }
    }

    void GameOver()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        fpsScript.RotationSpeed = 0f;
        gameOverMenu.SetActive(true);
        accuracyImage.fillAmount = accuracyFA / 10;
        ballHitText.text = (ballHit).ToString("0");
        percentageText.text = accuracy + "%";
        HUD.SetActive(false);
        
        if(ballHit <= 40)
        {
            performanceText.text = "Poor, Need Practice";
        }
        else if(ballHit <= 70)
        {
            performanceText.text = "Good, Can Improve";
        }
        else if(ballHit >= 70)
        {
            performanceText.text = "Well Done, Keep It Up";
        }

        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        crossheir.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}

targets should spawn and cursor should disappear and turn into crossheir

perhaps you never reset timescale off 0?

I am editing as after a conversation with ipodtouch I found my first part was incorrect since yield would cause the While(true) loop to exit.
What ipodtouch and bugfinder pointed out is a good point on what might be causing the problem. In the Gameover method you set the Time.timescale to 0 which does not restart when loading the scene again. It may be prudent to return it to 1 (Or whatever value you are using in-game, normally it is 1) at the end of the method or when starting the scene. It might be best to not even change Time.timescale as it can mess up code that might be running.
While I also understand and agree with iPodtouch that noOfballs would restart after loading the scene again. The variable doesn't appear in the provided code and it's important to establish it in the script to know its starting values where it is coming from.
private int noOfBalls = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        noOfBalls = 0;
        isGameOver = false;
        countDown = 120;
        StartCoroutine(Spawner());
        //InvokeRepeating("Spawner", 1, 1);
    }

The reason why the crosshair is likely not returning is because as previously mentioned Time.timescale is set to 0 and the script in charge of making said change is paused. It is also likely that the script in charge of changing the mouse to the crosshair is in another scene so it isn't been run again. Make sure that it is being called.


while (true) is fine in a coroutine that has a yield. -- 2) you don't need to reset the noOfBalls variable because reloading the scene destroys and recreates all objects - it will reset back to the default.


I wasn't sure if yields allowed the while(true) to exit and wanted to make sure it did exit.
For the noOfBalls restart I don't see another reason why it won't allow for the items to start respawning after restarting the scene. Especially given that the code doesn't show said variables being created and a value being given.

Most likely, it's just that they never change the Time.timeScale back from 0, so time never progresses, as mentioned in BugFinder's comment

If noOfBalls would get reset in the new scene wouldn't timescale also get reset once the new scene is loaded?

Time.timeScale is a static variable, it would never get reset / reinitialized. (because Unity doesn't create a new Time instance)

You right. I'll update my answer to include that on top so that it shows the problem with timeScale and remove the while(true) part. Since it isn't mentioned in the code where noOfBalls is created and the value is established I will keep it as something that the user needs to include.

Thank you.  Answers of you all really helped and problem is solved. Last thing can u suggest me how can I add an option to configure mouse sensitivity in the game.

The following tutorial I found has an in-depth explanation of how they did it.
https://m-ansley.medium.com/quickie-adding-mouse-sensitivity-options-c68da8e8ac5c
I don't know if there is technically a better version someone else knows about but this one seems good.

Thank You that's what i was searching for
